# Stack std::vectors to generate a matrix, similar to numpy.vstack

Tags: c++

Is there a way to stack, for example, two `std::vectors` of size N, to generate a matrix of 2 rows per N columns? Similar to Python's np.vstack function? Without using the inefficient vector of vectors (`std::vector<std::vector<type>>`) solution, or array of array?

Comment: Why do you think a vector of vectors is  inefficient? It is not an uncommon practice.

Comment: @lakeweb It's inefficient because it is not linear in memory.

Comment: Considering the question, I don't think so, but there are tons of matrix implementations out there. Just pick one.

Comment: I don't want to import a library just because of it

Comment: If you have a flat array and treat it as 2D, you will have overhead with the accessors that is probably just as expensive as a vect of vects. So you may want to look at the techniques use in boost::gil.

Comment: So i should stick with the common way, using matrix[2][N] ? Iterating every single vector?

Comment: @lakeweb ok, i will check it

Comment: Ok, gil is about processing images. They are stored flat, accessed 2D, and it should be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a 1d array. Multidimensional array syntax is evil.

```
const int width = 1024;
const int height = 768;
vector<float> matrix(0,width*height);

float getCell(int row, int col)
{
    return matrix[row * width + col];
}

float setCell(int row, int col, float val)
{
    matrix[row * width + col] = val;
}
```